# Duplicating several UI components in App Inventor 2

Tags: android, app-inventor

Is there any way to duplicate several UI components in [App Inventor 2](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/)?

E.g. in the following screenshot I would like to duplicate the RedHorizontalArrangement layout as well as the label and the TextBox it contains.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunetly no, you cannot copy and paste components, you need to re-drag them each time. You can at least copy & paste blocks (in blocks editor) which is often useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyboard shortcuts for selecting, copying and pasting components. For windows use Ctrl+C to copy and Ctrl+V to paste. For Mac or Linux use the alternatives